# Using Cramér's V to evaluate correlation between categorial variables with small numbers within contingency tables

Tags: categorical-data, chi-squared-test, small-sample, contingency-tables, cramers-v

I am evaluating correlations between categorical variables in a data set. I have seen Cramér's V is one way I can calculate this, and I know it takes the chi-squared statistic as one of the elements for computation.

The thing is some of my contingency tables have a lot of categories, sometimes with ending up with very low counts (and low expected values) in specific crosses. I know that the rule of thumb is that if an expected count is smaller than 5 the chi-square test should not be used, but I am under the impression this is because of the p-value estimation and not the statistic calculation itself.

Therefore my question is, do these small values within the contingency table exclude the use of Cramér's V (since it takes the chi-square statistic) in my analysis? If it does not, is there some type of correction/anything else I should be doing in these cases?

Thanks!